# Case insensitive with breeze predicate

Tags: breeze

Hi i am trying to find all case insensitive objects from my database but i'm unable to do so. I am using predicate to search for results .

```
condition = { and:
              [
                {or: [
                     { 'name_number': {'contains':this.livesearch}},
                     { '_p_wa_location_id_location.name': {'contains':this.livesearch}}
                   ]
                 },
                 {
                  and: filterCondition
                 }
              ]
}

query = query.where(condition);
```

I tried to use LocalQueryComparisonOptions with isCaseSensitive: false but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26218560/2517406